# Have a dynamic optional route parameter in index

Tags: php, laravel

I use :

```
Route::controller('home', 'HomeController');
```

in my routes to link all routes to my controller.

I have a `getIndex()` function in my controller that's executed when I go to '/home'.

I have a case where I'd like to route to '/home/slug', but not always.

I tried using `getIndex($slug)`, but it always asks for '/home/index/{slug?}'. I don't want index to appear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not possible using implicit controllers, as far as the documentation goes (as it seems to enforce RESTFUL pattern).

But your can create a new route just for that:

```
   Route::get('home/{slug}','HomeController@slugedIndex');
   Route::controller('home', 'HomeController');
```

Edit: as pointed by Steve the controller method must come after the get method so one does not overwrite the other.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Arthur Samarcos, it almost works, but I needed to put the get route before setting my controller route otherwise Laravel couldn't find the method associated (looked in the implicit controller methods).

The right code :

`Route::get('home/{slug}', 'HomeController@slugIndex');
Route::controller('home', 'HomeController');`

Comment: Thanks, I'll change the answer to avoid this issue.

Comment: Sorry @Arthur Samarcos, but it still doesn't work. I found the solution though,  I'll answer.

Answer (score 4):

Arthur's answer was :

```
Route::get('home/{slug}','HomeController@slugedIndex');
Route::controller('home', 'HomeController');
```

Although it doesn't work, because anything written after 'home/' will now go into the first route (and HomeController@slugedIndex).

I found a workaround though. I took out the route in routes.php :

```
Route::controller('home', 'HomeController');
```

Then in my HomeController, I used the [missingmethod()](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/controllers#handling-missing-methods) that's called whenever a method isn't found in the controller.

Here's the missing method :

```
public function missingMethod($parameters = array())
{
    $sSlug = is_string($parameters) ? $parameters : '';
    $oObject = Object::where('slug', $sSlug)->first();

    if ($oObject) {
        // slug code
    }
    else {
            // 404 code
    }
}
```